# API for Hours and Locations of Restaurants

Tags: ios, geolocation

I'm looking to make an iPhone app that utilizes the opening and closing times of restaurants, as well as their location. I found hoursmap.com as a site that does some of what I want, but I haven't found any others, specifically none with any API. As far as I can tell, neither Yelp nor Google Places has this feature. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are trying to do something different than the [hoursmap.com app](http://www.hoursmap.com/iphone_apps.php) already does?

Without an official API for Google/Yelp/others that grabs hours from an already existing database, you have limited options.  A couple I can think of:

1. Scraping Yelp/Google with a roll-your-own screen scraper that does live scraping when a user asks for a location.  This would be very hard to get right, and it probably breaks their TOS anyway, so be wary of that.
2. Building your own database by scraping various sites and keeping your own searchable database.  You can at least check the database for errors as it wouldn't be real-time (again, you may run into TOS issues).
3. Waiting for Yelp (or Google) to implement this ([it looks like people have been asking for the feature for a while](http://groups.google.com/group/yelp-developer-support/browse_thread/thread/270dba00d6bbd545/5058150af995f3d1?pli=1)).

Comment: Yeah, it'd be different than hoursmap.com, but i'd be implementing some of the features it uses. Thanks for the speedy reply, it's a shame this hasn't been added to any API yet. I think writing a scraper script or building a database to house all that data is a bit over my head at this point, unfortunately. Thanks again though, I appreciate it.

Comment: @Mason -- You might find it to be an interesting challenge to scrape the Yelp screens.  It would basically be a matter of loading the home page, performing the search, finding and following the link you want, and then looking for "Hours" and grabbing the data.  You'd definitely learn a good deal about html and how to parse it.  Good luck!